# play mp4 file in all browsers

Tags: html, jsp, cross-browser

Actually in my project i have a requirement to play the video file having extension .mp4.
Is there any way to play this video file in all browsers. I know that Firefox doesn't support the .mp4 format and

[Here i found that which browser supports for which format.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

But i want to play the only .mp4 file which is saved on my server side to be played by every browser. Can you tell me the generic code to work on all browser. I have found that multiple sources are given to play in different browser for same file. I think that they are saving the same file with several extension.

Please help me in this issue. I have been spend last 2 days for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using jquery.fineuploader.js in your jsp and 
by creating

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
//here you can write your uploading video code
element : document.getElementById('fine-uploader'),
        acceptFiles : 'video/mpeg',
        autoUpload: false,
        multiple: false,

});
// more code to write
// and for more details refer
```

http://fineuploader.com/fine-uploader-demo.html

your player html code

```
<div id="player" style="display: inline-block; position:relative; margin-top:-25px;">
<a href="http://get.adobe.com/fr/flashplayer/">You need to install the Flash plugin</a>                         
</div>
<div id="fine-uploader"></div>
```

you can play the .mp4 file uploade by using following code

```
function playVideo(videoUrl){
    $("#player").css('display', 'inline-block');
    $("#player > Object").remove();
    var flashvars= {};
    var video = {
            quality: "high",
            bgcolor: "#000000",
            allowScriptAccess: "always",
            allowFullScreen: "true",
            wmode: "transparent",               
            flashvars: "fichier="+videoUrl,
        };
    var attributes = {};
    flashObject("http://flash.webestools.com/flv_player/v1_27.swf", "player", "297", "180", "8", false, flashvars, video, attributes);
}
```

This will provide the player and play .mp4 file. works in firefox, but not in iexplorer.